# how to store output of expect into variable in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

How to i store the outcome of expect into a variable so that i can read that outcome in the subsequent tests.

What i am trying to achieve is that if Login page is not Loaded or if User is not Authenticated, i want to skip all other test, since those tests are not valid.

When i read the variable it returns 'undefined', expecting something like tru/false or pass/fail.

```
var result = expect(url).toContain("abcd");

if (result)
  continue=true;
else
  continue=false;
```

Comment: it seems to me you're on a wrong path, is it only to speed up specs execution when it fails?